# Using variable without declaration as an argument of function

Tags: php

Where is it defined in php docs that one can use undeclared variable as a function's argument e.g.:

```php
function parse_period(string $period) {
  if (!preg_match('/blah-blah/u', $period, $matches)) return null;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undeclared variables are initialised on their first use. It says so in the [PHP manual >> Language Reference >> Variables : Basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a
> very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a default value of
> their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans
> default to `FALSE`, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g.
> used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty
> array.
>
> #### Example #1 Default values of uninitialized variables
>
> ```
> <?php
> // Unset AND unreferenced (no use context) variable; outputs NULL
> var_dump($unset_var);
>
> // Boolean usage; outputs 'false' (See ternary operators for more on this syntax)
> echo($unset_bool ? "true\n" : "false\n");
>
> // String usage; outputs 'string(3) "abc"'
> $unset_str .= 'abc';
> var_dump($unset_str);
>
> // Integer usage; outputs 'int(25)'
> $unset_int += 25; // 0 + 25 => 25
> var_dump($unset_int);
>
> // Float/double usage; outputs 'float(1.25)'
> $unset_float += 1.25;
> var_dump($unset_float);
>
> // Array usage; outputs array(1) {  [3]=>  string(3) "def" }
> $unset_arr[3] = "def"; // array() + array(3 => "def") => array(3 => "def")
> var_dump($unset_arr);
>
> // Object usage; creates new stdClass object (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php)
> // Outputs: object(stdClass)#1 (1) {  ["foo"]=>  string(3) "bar" }
> $unset_obj->foo = 'bar';
> var_dump($unset_obj);
> ?>
> ```
>
> Relying on the default value of an uninitialized variable is
> problematic in the case of including one file into another which uses
> the same variable name. It is also a major security risk with
> register_globals turned on.

In your example, `$matches` is taken by `preg_match` as a reference. The call to `preg_match` will assign a value to it. But *before* `preg_match` makes that assignment, `$matches` will be `null` (see first example with `var_dump` in the quote above).